# notification.cancelAll() to FLAG_NO_CLEAR. for service

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I've put a notification for my service. and used FLAG_NO_CLEAR for that notification.
that works well.

but when my service is stopped then

```
    private void stopService()
    {   
            notificationMgr.cancelAll();
                stopSelf();
    }
```

it does not cancel the notification while stopping the service...
plz help...

Answer (score 1):

instead of using FLAG_NO_CLEAR now im using FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT and its working smooth.... 
:)